# get lat and lng from array of objects on React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm trying to get the lat and lng props from this array, but when I log them to console I get this:

*3 ƒ (){return a} f () {return b}*

```
steps_start_locations =[{"lat":45.2003571,"lng":12.122561899999937},
                       {"lat":45.200382,"lng":12.122545400000035},
                       {"lat":45.2046145,"lng":12.135933199999954}]

steps_start_locations.forEach( location => {
          var lat = location.lat;
          var lng = location.lng;
          console.log(lat + ' ' + lng)
      });
```

how to print correctly?

Comment: You have a typo, your variable is `step_start_locations` and the variable you're iterating over is `step(S)_start_locations`. Fixing this fixes your code.

Comment: working great here when fixed variable name and remove `: ` from last line

Answer (score 0):

As the comments by @Dan and @guijob already mentioned just fix the spelling error in the forEach section and remove the ":" at the end of the code. Here is a snippet with a running version of your code:

```js
step_start_locations =[{"lat":45.2003571,"lng":12.122561899999937},
                       {"lat":45.200382,"lng":12.122545400000035},
                       {"lat":45.2046145,"lng":12.135933199999954}]

step_start_locations.forEach( location => {
    var lat = location.lat;
    var lng = location.lng;
    console.log(lat + ' ' + lng)
});
```

Comment: I corrected it but the output I get it's always the same. I'm working with React.. maybe is it why it doesn't work?

Comment: The output is not the same in the console.log shown in the snippet. It is iterating the array or lat/long values. is the forEach loop working right on your end? Maybe try using a for loop and look close at which values are being consoled as it loops.

Comment: If i do it with a for loop the output is the same, ( function (){return a} function (){return b} )

Comment: Is your output not the same as what is shown in the snippet above? I don't see how you are getting output different than mine. Maybe you can add a snippet to your question that shows what you are getting?

Comment: I posted my output @MUlferts

Comment: You should edit your original answer and append the extra stuff at the end instead of adding a new answer, but anyways, try just using a console.log in the loop to show location. console.log(location);

Comment: I don't really know anything about react.js, but it looks like lat and long are returning functions for some reason. What does lat.a or lat.b produce?

Comment: I solved it! I changed location.lat, location.lng in location.lat() and location.lng()

Comment: Oh shoot, nice that works out. The lat and long variables were stored at functions then somehow.

Comment: Yep, that was the reason of the output " ƒ (){return a} f () {return b}  "  . Thank you for your support! @MUlferts

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this and send me your feed back? You shouldn't have problem with this:

```
for (var i =0 ; i <steps_start_locations.lenght ;i++)
{
   var lat = steps_start_locations[i].lat;
   var lng = steps_start_locations[i].lng;
   console.log(lat + ' ' + lng)
}
```